# Hold several jobs in Slurm

Tags: slurm

I know that for a specific job ID, I can use `scontrol hold $JOBID`.

How can I hold jobs for several IDs or/and hold jobs for a range of jobs ids (e.g. scontrol hold 294724-294749)?

Also, how can I hold jobs based on my `$USER`?

Comment: Try with a loop, or `xargs`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, if all your jobs have the same name, you can use

```
scontrol hold <jobname>
```

to hold them all.

But the `scontrol` command accepts a list of job IDs, which can be either space- or comma-separated. So if your jobs have consecutive job IDs, you can use Bash's `{1..n}` ([Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)) construct to generate the list and feed it to scontrol:

```
scontrol hold {294724..294749}
```

Otherwise, one common idiom is to use `squeue`'s output formatting capabilities to generate `scontrol` commands and feed them to a shell:

```
squeue --noheader --user $USER --format "scontrol hold %i" | sh
```

(When doing that, it is wise to first run the squeue command without piping to `sh` to review its output before running it again through `sh`)

Comment: if you add `-h` or `--noheader` it will surpress `JOBID` in the output, eg `squeue -h --user $USER --format "scontrol hold %i" | sh` which will fix the error `Invalid job id specified for job JOBID
slurm_suspend error: Invalid job id specified`

Comment: Indeed I forgot the `-h` in the answer. Thanks